# How to remove Vysor Screen Capture in list of Chrome Cameras?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, permissions, camera, vysor

I have previously installed Vysor in my Macbook Pro. I uninstalled it & set my default camera to FaceTime HD. However, when I use a webcam in my browser, it still defaults to Vysor Screen Capture Camera (which I already uninstalled). How can I remove it from the list and completely uninstall other cameras, so that my browser will open the FaceTime HD camera by default in Chrome?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following solution given below worked for me.

Open Finder > Macintosh HD, then locate /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-ins/DAL. Remove the Vysor plugin. Restart browser.